# clazz.getDeclaredFields() returns Set not the Class in the Set

Tags: java

This seems simple but I'm having trouble finding an answer. I'm using getDeclaredFields() on a class and for some of the fields it returns Set instead of the Class in the set.

```
    for(Field f: clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
//f is Set<Object> but f.getType() returns java.util.Set, not Object, how do I access the //Object? }
```

Comment: Try [`getTypeParameters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters%28%29) on `f.getType()`

Comment: @MiserableVariable That returns the name of the type parameter variable, ie. `E`. `Returns an array of TypeVariable objects that represent the type variables declared by the generic declaration represented by this GenericDeclaration object, in declaration order.`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you are correct, indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the generic type of the field.

```
for(Field f: clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
    Type type = f.getGenericType();
    ParameterizedType impl = (ParameterizedType) type;
    Class genericArgument = (Class) impl.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    System.out.println(genericArgument);
}
```

which prints

```
class java.lang.String
```